# What is the way to create tcl script for ddos attack in ns2 simulator?

Tags: ns2, ddos, congestion-control

I want to plot ddos attack in ns2 simulator.also want to calculate the packet dropping rate and comparing the xgraph of the traffic.

Comment: If people downvote because of the word "ddos", please don't. Ns2 is about network simulation: users learn, among other things, to deal with ddos attacks. To do that, they need to set up ddos attacks on their own systems. This is, unless I'm very mistaken, a "white hat" question.

Comment: **aqm-dos** etc. https://sites.google.com/site/cwzhangres/home/files/ ... **Blue** https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5cyot6brav933q/ns-blue.tar.gz?dl=0 **LeoDOS** https://github.com/mleoking/LeoDoS

Comment: »» create tcl script for ddos attack in ns2 «« : A script.tcl won't do alone. You will have to add two or three of { aqm-dos, Blue, LeoDOS } to ns2. Some examles.tcl are included in the packages.